# AS3 FLVPlayback occasionally stuck in buffering on launch

Tags: actionscript-3, buffering, flvplayback

I've got a Flash CS6 FLA with an instance of the FLVPlayback component (2.5.0.26) and an instance of the Progress Bar component on the stage, loading an external FLV.

I'm trying to preload a specific percentage of video before playing.

When hosted on a server, the video launches and plays as expected 80% of the time, but 20% of the time the video gets stuck in a buffering state on launch (blank area where video should be), and I can't get it to play through AS3 or by clicking the play button on the skin controls. Oddly, if I refresh the browser when it's stuck I see a glimpse of the video before the page reloads and then plays the video as expected.

I've tested on a Mac (Lion) in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari and had the same results.
The video problem gets worse if I limit my bandwidth using SpeedLimit.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
public class SimpleVideoLoad extends MovieClip {

    var isLoaded:Boolean = false;

    public function SimpleVideoLoad() {
        // constructor code
        loadVideo();
    }
    function loadVideo():void
    { 
        my_FLVPlybk.x = 0;
        my_FLVPlybk.y = 0;
        my_FLVPlybk.width = 743;
        my_FLVPlybk.height = 300;
        my_FLVPlybk.source = "CARSdotCOM_OLD.flv";
        //preloader component
        pb.source = my_FLVPlybk;
        pb.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandlerPB); 
    }
    //progress bar component
    function progressHandlerPB(event:ProgressEvent):void { 
        var percentOfVideoLoaded = pb.percentComplete;
        if (percentOfVideoLoaded>10 && isLoaded == false){      
            isLoaded = true;
            my_FLVPlybk.play();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: if you are loading this locally, your progress event might not be firing sometimes since it loads so quickly.  Try loading it from a remote url and I believe you will get the results you expected.

Comment: Try looking into the LoaderMax library, part of the Greensock framework...It greatly simplifies the loading process, and offers a handful of useful functions that can skate around a lot of common issues, especially in the realm of video playback. http://greensock.com